# Clickable InfoBubble in Google Maps API 3

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, infobubble

Good day! 
I just want to ask if an InfoBubble can have a listener. I tried to insert the text of the InfoBubble in a div and insert an onclick command there, but nothing happens.

Thanks in advance. By the way I am currently developing an android application, and using webview to display the map.

Comment: jetpro - do you mean that you want to insert an event listener to invoke the infobubble into being displayed or add an event listener onto the close button of the infobubble?? or something else altogether

Comment: Oh sorry. I think my question is not that complete.
This is my situation, I am fetching my markers' lat and lng values from an online database.
What I want to do is, I want to retrieve the id(primary key) of a tapped marker of a particular place and bring it back to my android application.

My only problem is I don't retrieve the id. That's why I asked if there is any easier way of assigning a listener when this infoBubble is clicked.

Comment: hey jetpro - put that full detail with any additional info into the original question and i think you'll get a few good answers. and btw - i'm still not 100% clear on the requirement, so best to redo your question as a list of problems and requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, jetpro,

here's what I do in a similar scenario using javascript:

```
/* json data object requires:
data.Id,
data.Lat,
data.Lng,
data.Name,
data.Address,
data.Date
*/
function DisplayMapEvent(data, targetDiv) {
    var latlng, options, map, contentString, infowindow, marker;

    // setup our variables
    latlng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(data.Lat, data.Lng);
    options =
        {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

    // create the map inside our map <div> and apply the options
    map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(targetDiv), options);
    map.setOptions(options);

    // info to display in the infowindow popup
    contentString =
            '<div>' +
                '<b style="color: #DC6852;">' + data.Name + '</b><br />' +
                'Where: ' + data.Address + '<br />' +
                'When: '  + data.Date    + '<br />' +
            '</div>';

    // info/marker and popup objects setup
    infowindow = new window.google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
    });

    // add the usual suspect event handlers
    window.google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

    // to allow us to repoen a map marker infowindow if closed
    window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    // open infowindow on map once rendered
    infowindow.open(map, marker);

    // sit back and wonder at the glory of google maps mow :-)
}
```

In my case, I'm passing a json object into the `DisplayMapEvent` function, but you could rejig this to your own requirement. This function is called anytime I wish to add a new marker onto my map, so you may be able to lift this wholesale and refactor as required.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for exerting some effort to provide this answer to me. This really gave me some idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add listener like this

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(infoBubble2.bubble_, 'click', function(){..});
```

Have fun!